# Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, json, mime-types

I have a map on this page https://www.americansouthwest.net/area-map.shtml
which has just in the last week or so stopped displaying the overlay elements, because of this error:

Refused to execute script from 'https://www.americansouthwest.net/javascript/data.json' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

The local version of the map still works

What is the easiest way to fix this?

Comment: JSON is data, so it isn't executable - it's the `var data =` that makes it NOT json - it's javascript - what did you change?

Comment: I changed nothing, as far as I know!

Comment: But, I see that if I change the suffix of that file from json to js, then it works

Comment: Yes, that would make sense